# Date Conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a date in following format

`'2013-09-22 00:00:00.000'`

I need this in `22-09-2013, Sunday` and `22-Sep-2013, Sunday` formats. I dint find any convert function to get days along with.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to use the COLLATE clause to pick another locale and thus format for the statement: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this on your presentation layer?

Comment: @u07ch : I use this in only one timezome and used in report extraction. So not much focus on timezone required.
anyway. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use CONVERT() and DATENAME() functions like below :

```
1) select CONVERT(varchar(20), getdate(),105) + ',' + datename(DW, getdate())

2) select REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), getdate(),106),' ','-') + ',' + datename(DW, getdate())
```

Result is

```
07-11-2013, Thursday and 07-Nov-2013, Thursday
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 103), ' ', '-'), '/', '-') + ', ' + datename(dw,getdate()) AS [DD-Mon-YYYY];
```

And

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-'), '/', '-') + ', ' + datename(dw,getdate()) AS [DD-Mon-YYYY];
```

Output:

`07-11-2013, Thursday` and `07-Nov-2013, Thursday`

(You might not need the first REPLACE function. Without it, the second date for me showed up as `07/11/2013, Thursday`. The replace simply replaces the `'/'` with `'-'` like you specified).

I agree with others suggesting that the conversion should be handled in the client application, though. Especially if the application will be used in different timezones. Hard-coding the date format in SQL then would possibly lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Dates stored in SQL-Server without any format. It is client application (e.g. ssms) formats a date.

If you need to format date on server side you can convert it into varchar using [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) functions.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50),@date,110)+', '+ DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105) + ', '+ DATENAME (weekday ,GETDATE())  AS [DD-MM-YYYY, DAY],
        REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-') + ', '+ DATENAME (weekday ,GETDATE()) AS [DD-Mon-YYYY, DAY]
```